# How to tweak std::stod (string to double) for decimal separator and number of digits

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, type-conversion, locale

is there a way to tweak std::stod() in order to increase the number of decimal digits in the (string to double) conversion and to force it to use the US locale?

I have a Qt application that can be run in both console or gui mode:

```
if (opt->getFlag( 'c' ) || opt->getFlag( "console" ) ){
  ThreadManager  modelMainThread;
  modelMainThread.runFromConsole(inputFileName,scenarioName);
}
else {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow mainWin;
  mainWin.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Within this application I have a string to double method that wraps the new C++11 stod:

```
double s2d ( const string &string_h) const {
  try {
    return stod(string_h);
  } catch (...) {
    if (string_h == "") return 0;
    else {
      cout << "error!" << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Odd enough, while in the console mode the string to double conversion expects a string with dot as decimal separator, in the gui mode it instead expects a string with comma.
Furthermore, as I was previously using istringstream:

```
istringstream totalSString( valueAsString );
totalSString >> valueAsDouble;
```

I noticed that stod truncates the resulting double to just 3 decimal digits, much less than istringstream.

So is there a way to increase the number of decimal digits and to force std::stod to use the US locale for the conversion ?

Thanks :-)

**EDITED**:

If I try this script:

```
// testing stod() ..
vector<string> numbers;
numbers.push_back("123.1234567890");
numbers.push_back("123.1234");
numbers.push_back("123,1234567890");
numbers.push_back("123,1234");
double outd;
for(uint i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
    try {
        outd =  stod(numbers[i]);
        cout << "Conversion passed: " << numbers[i] << "  -  " << outd << endl;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Conversion DID NOT passed: " << numbers[i] << "  -  " <<endl;
    }
}
```

I got these results:

"console" mode:

```
Conversion passed: 123.1234567890  -  123.123
Conversion passed: 123.1234  -  123.123
Conversion passed: 123,1234567890  -  123
Conversion passed: 123,1234  -  123
```

"gui" mode:

```
Conversion passed: 123.1234567890  -  123
Conversion passed: 123.1234  -  123
Conversion passed: 123,1234567890  -  123.123
Conversion passed: 123,1234  -  123.123
```

So clearly there is something influencing stod() behaviour !

Comment: `stod` is defined as using `sprintf` with `%f`. It's not configurable.

Comment: If you're concerned with raw runtime speed and want locale independence, and are _not_ concerned about potentially-worse compile times, [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/).Qi is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: Stumbled upon this and was shocked that stod truncates the values. But the problem is that std::cout doesn't output the whole value. You have to set higher precision: std::cout<<std::setprecision(16);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::stod` and its kin were designed to provide a **simple**, quick conversion from a string to a numeric type. (full disclosure: it's my design) So, no, no locales; what you see is what you get.

Comment: So, just for curiosity, why I have this different behaviour in gui/console mode ? There must be something that the Qt libraries set that influence the stod behavior.

Comment: @Antonello - sorry, I have no experience with Qt.

Comment: Just for clarification, stod() IS influenced by the current locale, at least in GCC. So for example to be sure it will use the dot as decimal separator one should use #include <clocale> and setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")  (that's the default, but clearly Qt must set it to the running computer locale so you need to override the Qt override ;-) )

Comment: @Antonello - thanks for the reminder. I was recalling a suggestion to add an explicit locale argument to all of the string conversions functions, which I adamantly opposed. `stod` is specified in terms of the behavior of the function `strtod`, which does depend on the global locale.

Comment: This answer is wrong, which you admitted in the comments. Why not edit it to fix?

Answer (score 12):

`std::stod` is defined in terms of `std::strtod`, which is inherited from the C standard library. The C function `strtod` works in terms of the C locale, accessible via the `setlocale` function from the `<locale.h>` header.

In C++, the C locale is still accessible via `std::setlocale` function in the `<clocale>` header, and it does influence both `std::strtod` and `std::stod`.

Qt's `QApplication` uses `std::setlocale` to set the user-chosen locale. Thus whenever you use a C-locale-dependent function in a GUI Qt application, you'll have locale-dependent radix point.

Now, to force a particular locale for numbers, you can use `std::setlocale` as follows. Note though, that this can break multithreaded apps, since C locale is a thread-global state. The example below will set program's locale temporarily to `LC_NUMERIC=C`, and restore the setting after calling `std::stod`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void test()
{
    for(auto s : {"123.1234567890",
                  "123.1234",
                  "123,1234567890",
                  "123,1234"})
    {
        // Save locale setting
        const std::string oldLocale=std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,nullptr);
        // Force '.' as the radix point. If you comment this out,
        // you'll get output similar to the OP's GUI mode sample
        std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");
        try
        {
            const auto outd=std::stod(s);
            std::cout << "Conversion succeeded: " << s << "  =>  "
                      << outd << '\n';
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Conversion FAILED   : " << s << "  =>  ???\n";
        }
        // Restore locale setting
        std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,oldLocale.c_str());

    }
}

#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Test in normal console mode\n";
    test();
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "Test in GUI mode\n";
    test();
}
```

Output:

```
Test in normal console mode
Conversion succeeded: 123.1234567890  =>  123.123
Conversion succeeded: 123.1234  =>  123.123
Conversion succeeded: 123,1234567890  =>  123
Conversion succeeded: 123,1234  =>  123
Test in GUI mode
Conversion succeeded: 123.1234567890  =>  123.123
Conversion succeeded: 123.1234  =>  123.123
Conversion succeeded: 123,1234567890  =>  123
Conversion succeeded: 123,1234  =>  123
```

Comment: It works the same way with gtkmm : in `main` add `std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");` *after* `Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);`

Comment: I know this answer is 2.5 years old, nevertheless: the memory your `oldLocale` variable points to may become invalid on the next call `std::setlocale` just one codeline below! Documentation says: _A **copy** of the returned string along with the category used in this call to `std::setlocale` may be used later in the program to restore the locale back to the state at the end of this call._ You'd probably want `std::string oldLocale(std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,nullptr));` instead (and `std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,oldLocale.c_str());` to restore).

Comment: @MarcoFreudenberger you're right, I've fixed it now.

Comment: hang on a sec, shouldn't 3rd and 4th call fail, e.g. 123,1234567890 with that call to `setlocale`?

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski no, trailing characters are ignored (and, if we passed a non-null `pos` argument, we'd get an offset to them).

Comment: Oh cheers, should've read the reference better! So effectively the `std::invalid_argument` is only ever gonna be thrown iff the first character is not a digit already? That might lead to dozens of silent errors, cus we should not only wrap a call to `std::stod` in a `try-catch` but also compare the `*pos` value :( but I should be complaining to the committee rather than here :P

Answer (score 3):

`std::stod` is a somehow generic way of converting a `std::string` to a double. If you want something more specific, you should implement it yourself.

For example:

```
double my_stod(const std::string &valueAsString) {
    istringstream totalSString( valueAsString );
    double valueAsDouble;
    // maybe use some manipulators
    totalSString >> valueAsDouble;
    if(!totalSString)
        throw std::runtime_error("Error converting to double");    
    return valueAsDouble;
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I was actually using, but it's pretty slow, and I'm quite concerned with speed..

Comment: Well, the question was "how to teak std::stod". The answer sadly is "you can't". If you really find out that using stringstreams is a bottleneck in your code, you should optimize it. But remember, don't optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid threading issues when setting the locale and using `strtod`, I would use `istringstream`:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>

[[nodiscard]] std::optional<double>
toDouble( const std::string& stringToConvert)
{
    std::istringstream streamToConvert( stringToConvert );
    streamToConvert.imbue( std::locale( "C" ) );
    double result = 0.0;
    streamToConvert >> result;

    if ( streamToConvert.fail() || streamToConvert.bad() || !streamToConvert.eof() ) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you really don't want to use `istringstream`, you could try to call [`std::num_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get), which is what `istringstream` calls internally.

Answer (score 0):

`std::num_get()` could be used which is what `std::istringstream` is using under the hood. Since `std::num_get()` is using iterators as input anything could be used here which offers an iterator returning `char` values, for example `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <ios>

std::locale classic_locale_with_own_facet;

template< typename T >
inline bool from_string( const std::string &str, T &value )
{
    // This code was taken from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get
    // but we use std::string instead of std::istringstream since it's about 3 times faster.

    struct ios_base : public std::ios_base {} s3;
    s3.imbue( classic_locale_with_own_facet );
    std::ios::iostate err = std::ios_base::goodbit;
    std::use_facet< std::num_get< char, std::string::const_iterator > >( s3.getloc() ).get( str.begin(), str.end(), s3, err, value );
    return err == std::ios_base::eofbit;  // return true if no error has occurred and all characters have been read, false otherwise
}

int main()
{
    // Construct a copy of std::locale::classic() except for the facet of type std::num_get< char, std::string::const_iterator >
    classic_locale_with_own_facet = std::locale( std::locale::classic(), new std::num_get< char, std::string::const_iterator > );

    double d;

    if ( from_string( "123.1234567890", d ) )
        std::cout << "d = " << std::setprecision( 12 ) << d << "\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Conversation failed\n";

    if ( from_string( "-1.23e-6", d ) )
        std::cout << "d = " << std::setprecision( 12 ) << d << "\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Conversation failed\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Since C++17 this problem has become obsolete since `std::from_chars()` could be used here which operates independent from the current locale.