# when running a function from my project, the stod() function gives an incorrect result

Tags: c++, string, double, nlohmann-json

I have three files - a json file, my project, and test (main.cpp)

json file:

```json
{
    "points": {
        "range": 25,
        "step": 0.001
    }
}
```

in file `main.cpp` this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using json = nlohmann::json;


int main()
{
    std::ifstream jsonFile("json/settings.json");
    json parsedFile = json::parse(jsonFile);
    jsonFile.close();

    double parsed_number;
    printf("string: %s\nstod return: %f\n", 
           parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump().c_str(), 
           stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump()));

    printf("type: %s\n", typeid(stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump())).name());
    
    parsed_number = stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump());
    printf("step: %f\n", parsed_number);

    std::string temporary = "0.001";
    parsed_number = stod(temporary);
    printf("temporary: %s \nstep: %f \n", temporary.c_str(), parsed_number);
}

/* outputs:
string: 0.001
stod returns: 0.001000
type: d
step: 0.001000
temporary: 0.001 
step: 0.001000
*/
```

This is the correct answer.

But in my project, the same code:

```cpp
    std::ifstream jsonFile(json_filename);
    assert(jsonFile.is_open());
    json parsedFile = json::parse(jsonFile);
    jsonFile.close();
    //range = stoi(parsedFile["points"]["range"].dump());

    double parsed_number;
    printf("string: %s\nstod returns: %f\n", 
           parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump().c_str(), 
           stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump()));

    printf("type: %s\n", typeid(stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump())).name());
    
    parsed_number = stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump());
    printf("step: %f\n", parsed_number);

    std::string temporary = "0.001";
    parsed_number = stod(temporary);
    printf("temporary: %s \nstep: %f \n", temporary.c_str(), parsed_number);

/* outputs:
string: 0.001
stod returns: 0,000000
type: d
step: 0,000000
temporary: 0.001 
step: 0,000000
*/
```

That is, from the string `"0.001"` in my project, the number `0` is obtained, and in the test file, the correct `0.001`.

I tried to see what `stod(parsedFile["points"]["step"].dump())` returns.
I also tried to convert `string` to double, you can see the result for yourself.

How can I get around this problem without using crutches?

C++20 standard.

I can't find any answers to this...

Comment: Do you notice the output containing a decimal *comma* instead of a decimal point? Are you on a system with locale or regional settings that uses comma instead of point for decimals? Unfortunately it goes both ways, so all "input" needs to use comma as well.

Comment: On another note, please don't use `printf` for output. With the `%f` specifier you're lucky that it also works for `double`, but for other formats you might not be as lucky. Mismatching format specifier and argument type lead to *undefined behavior*. Please use the type-safe `std::cout` and the overloaded stream output operators `<<`.

Comment: Your locale settings are wrong.  For parsing configuration files, you really should be using locale-agnostic functions (good luck finding them in any modern framework, even though they are fundamental to data processing).  Yes, you can jump through all the hoops of creating a stream and imbuing the "C" locale... but a feature that requires extra work to turn it off is not really a feature after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works with comma in my project.

Comment: @frnzzz: Perhaps it "works with comma", but then it is no longer JSON :(

Comment: @user:440558 I used cout all the time, but my father came up to me and said it was better to use printf(). But I will follow your advice

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316972/how-to-tweak-stdstod-string-to-double-for-decimal-separator-and-number-of-di  Don't hack around with your JSON input just to fix this.

Comment: Somehow I got tagged on that comment. `printf` has it's uses, but it's very easy to use incorrectly and with most of those incorrect uses, there is no warning, no error, just garbled output or a program crash. Use `printf` where it makes sense to use it, where it does the job better and is easier to read, but use it with caution.

Comment: Since you use C++20, check if your compiler supports [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) which is safer than `std::printf`.

Comment: C++17 has [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars), which is locale-independent.

Comment: @heapunderrun There's really no need since the library has built-in functions to do the conversion safely.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the library function `get<T>()` to extract the value from the `json` object and not do it yourself with `std::stod` which is affected by the current locale.

In your case:

```cpp
double parsed_number = parsedFile["points"]["step"].get<double>();
```

---

You could also create a `from_json` overload an populate objects directly if you wish:

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using json = nlohmann::json;

json read_json_file() {
    if(std::ifstream jsonFile("json/settings.json"); jsonFile) {
        return json::parse(jsonFile);
    }
    return {};
}

struct points {
    int range;
    double step;
};

void from_json(const json& j, points& p) {
    auto& jpnts = j.at("points");
    jpnts.at("range").get_to(p.range);
    jpnts.at("step").get_to(p.step);
}

int main() {
    auto parsedFile = read_json_file();
    auto pnts = parsedFile.get<points>();

    std::cout << pnts.range << '\n' << pnts.step << '\n';
}
```